# Short Project: Electronics Inventory

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I'm doing my short project that acts as a type of electronic store inventory. Here's the list of item's number, description, quantity, and price from the text file:

```
65321,Tablet,54,150.00
91524,Monitors,24,125.50
25013,Printers,30,65.75
32841,Router,67,90.15
53214,Modem,50,50.50
26442,Hard Drive,14,40.89
30224,Power Supplies,44,125.44
41557,CPU,39,149.54
71561,Headphones,40,75.24
```

This is what I've done so far:

InventoryCalculate.java

```
ArrayList<BookItem> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Data\\stock.txt"));
        String line;
        line = input.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
        int itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        String description = tokens[1];
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        double unitCost = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);

        System.out.println("Inventory Item");
        System.out.println("Number  Description           Quantity  Unit Price          Value");
```

Inventorystock.java

```
public class InventoryItem {

private int itemNumber;
private String description;
private int quantity;
private double unitCost;

public InventoryItem(int itemNumber, String description, int quantity, double unitCost) {
    this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    this.description = description;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.unitCost = unitCost;
}

public int getItemNumber() {
    return itemNumber;
}

public void setItemNumber(int itemNumber) {
    this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public double getUnitCost() {
    return unitCost;
}

public void setUnitCost(double unitCost) {
    this.unitCost = unitCost;
} }
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the total value of each item. Here what I need to see the result look like this

Expected output:

```
Number  Description           Quantity  Unit Price         Value
 65321  Tablets                     54      150.00      8,100.00
 91524  Monitors                    24      125.50      3,012.00
 25013  Printers                    30       65.75      1,972.50
 32841  Routers                     67       90.15      6,040.05
 53214  Modems                      50       50.50      2,525.00
 26442  Hard Drives                 14       40.89        572.46
 30224  Power Supplies              44      125.44      5,519.36
 41557  CPU                         39      149.54      5,832.06
 71561  Headphones                  40       75.24      3,009.60
```

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty? Are you asking how to obtain the value 8100 based on the unit price of 150 and the quantity of 54? Why do you think you need to *set* this value of 8100. You don't need to *set* it. You need to *get* it in order to *print* it.

Comment: I mean how to get the total value of each item. Sorry, I just typo.

Comment: A banana costs 5 dollars, you buy 4 bananas, how much do you need to pay? 5*4. It's a simple multiplication. Same here. You have 54 tablets. Each costs 150. So the total is 54*150 = 8100. Is that *really* what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that takes the total quantity of the item, multiplies it by the unit cost and then returns the result. Add the following code to your InventoryItem class.

```
 public double getTotalValueOfItem()
 {
      return unitCost * quantity;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another property in InventoryItem class as totalValue and add setter, getter methods with your logic. The best way to keep total value calculation in the method that you're displaying details.

```
public class InventoryItem {

    private int itemNumber;
    private String description;
    private int quantity;
    private double unitCost;
    private double totalValue;

    public InventoryItem(int itemNumber, String description, int quantity, double unitCost) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.unitCost = unitCost;
    }

    public int getItemNumber() {
        return itemNumber;
    }

    public void setItemNumber(int itemNumber) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getUnitCost() {
        return unitCost;
    }

    public void setUnitCost(double unitCost) {
        this.unitCost = unitCost;
    }     

    public double getTotalValue() {
        return totalValue;
    }

    public void setTotalValue(int quantity, double unitCost) {
        this.totalValue = (double) quantity * unitCost;
    } 

}
```

You can add this method to print the item details

```
public void printDetails() {
 System.out.println("Number\tDescription\tQuantity\tUnit Price\tValue");
 List < InventoryItem > inventoryItemsList = new ArrayList < InventoryItem > ();
 inventoryItemsList.add(new InventoryItem(1, "description 1", 2, 50.0));
 inventoryItemsList.add(new InventoryItem(2, "description 2", 3, 40.0));
 for (InventoryItem item: inventoryItemsList) {
     System.out.println(item.itemNumber + "\t" + item.description + "\t" + item.quantity + "\t" + item.unitCost + "\t" + item.totalValue);
 }
}
```

You can store the details of inventory items as a String or as a List as demonstrated in printDetails method. Hope this "printDetails" method solved your issue. If you really want to store item details as a string then you can store all item details into a string array.

Make sure to import required libraries and model classes in following way.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import <package>.InventoryItem;
```

Comment: That's what I think. Another question: I want to know how to store these four pieces of information (item's number, description, quantity, price, and totalValue) into a single line (look at my expected output).

Comment: @BeckyLin I have added "printDetails" method and if you display this in console/terminal need to use something different for \t - tab spaces. There I have use an ArrayList only to demonstrate.

Comment: I just added it in InventoryCalculate.java but the red line appeared on `for (InventoryItem item : inventoryItemsList)`

Comment: You have to import following libraries java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList. Hope you have added that. It should be a different issue. What is the type of inventoryItemsList? it should be a ArrayList.